# How to set up Redis authentication on Slanger

Tags: ruby, redis, pusher

[Slanger](https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger) is an open source server implementation of the Pusher protocol written in Ruby.

It requires Redis to run, where it keeps the global state to be shared between multiple Slanger instances.

If Redis is configured via [redis.conf](https://redis.io/topics/security) to use authentication, where should I set up the Slanger to know the Redis password?

I tried to read the Slanger documentation, but I haven't found it.

Inside the Slanger source code I found this connection creation, passing a string parameter, which looks like a host address:

[image]

Is there some way of passing the password together the host, like a connection string or editing the source code to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem doing the following:

```
vi /etc/redis.conf
```

Then searching **requirepass** (using / and n to search and navigate) and uncommenting it, replacing forbared (default password) to the choosen password.

Then on Slanger initialization I found that I can pass a connection string with an empty username and the choosen password (I am using Redis 3.x, according the documentation the username is available on some new versions features), as example a connection string using the password "foobared":

```
slanger --app_key your-pusher-key --secret your-pusher-secret --redis_address redis://:foobared@192.168.1.222:6379/0
```